# ParseError at [row,col]:[20,9] Message: expected start or end tag

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi when i try to build my project, i 've got something like this: **ParseError at [row,col]:[20,9]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app** Below is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.songs.songs">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.AboutApp">

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.SongActivity" >

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line that isn't inside its tag

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
</activity>
```

Just remove this line in all occurrences

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or put it inside the tag, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.AboutApp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.SongActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```